# Gmail ReviewAction Schema not POSTing to service

Tags: email, google-schemas

I marked up my email and sent it using the Gmail App Script tutorial.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "EmailMessage",
  "action": {
    "@type": "ReviewAction",
    "review": {
      "@type": "Review",
      "itemReviewed": {
        "@type": "FoodEstablishment",
        "name": "Joe's Diner"
      },
      "reviewRating": {
        "@type": "Rating",
        "bestRating": "5",
        "worstRating": "1"
      }
    },
    "handler": {
      "@type": "HttpActionHandler",
      "url": "http://gmail-demo-heroku-123.herokuapp.com/review",
      "requiredProperty": {
        "@type": "Property",
        "name": "review.reviewRating.ratingValue"
      },
      "optionalProperty": {
        "@type": "Property",
        "name": "review.reviewBody"
      },
      "method": "http://schema.org/HttpRequestMethod/POST"
    }
  },
  "description": "We hope you enjoyed your meal at Joe's Diner. Please tell us about it."
}
</script>
```

It shows up correctly in my inbox. It shows a review button. When I click on it it has a field for the body of the review and 5 stars that you can select. The Call To Action says publish on Gmail.com which is a little strange (and may point to the core issue), but I'm not sure.

When I click on the review button in Gmail and fill out the form, it provides the following error when I submit it.

```
Unable to send rating to gmail.com. Click on the stars again to retry.
```

The endpoint I provide can be reached and returns a 200 when I call it from console.

```
payload = {'review.reviewRating.ratingValue' : '2.0', 'review.reviewBody' : 'incredible'}
requests.post('http://gmail-demo-heroku-123.herokuapp.com/review',payload)
<Response [200]>
```

Why is Gmail giving this error? Is there a good way to debug this request coming from Gmail? Also, why is the Review Card saying Publish to Gmail.com in the Call To Action? The Schema.org markup appears to be correct in the email.

Comment: Does it need to be SSL?